# Use google drive api with API token string only

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I am trying to authenticate and download files from google drive using only the API key as credentials. I have tried a lot and searched google and every where else but could not find a way to do it. I know I can use service account IAM admin or Oauth consent but I have a use case I do not want those two. If there is a way please tell me.

I found only this example and this also gives error

```
import requests

api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'

# Make a request to the Drive API using the API key
response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', params={'key': api_key})

# Print the response
print(response.json())
```

The error I get is

```
{'error': {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientFilePermissions', 'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.'}], 'code': 403, 'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.'}}
```

I only want to download files from my account or in other words the account on which the API token is generated

Comment: is the file public?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment from Google API documentation, it is not possible to authenticate using only the API token, the API token only identifies your project to Google(i.e tell Google what project you are trying to connect to and also monitor your usage of resources) and is not for authentication purposes

To access Google Drive resources, you need to authenticate using one of the supported authentication methods such as OAuth 2.0, Service Account, or Google Sign-In. These authentication methods provide secure access to Google APIs, and they require a set of credentials such as client ID, client secret, and access token.

OAuth 2.0 and Service Account are the recommended authentication methods for accessing Google Drive resources.

If you have a use case where you absolutely can't use the available options, you can reach out to Google cloud support team for help.